# App launch issue in React native track player

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, exoplayer, react-native-video

I am using this package `react-native-track-player` - [link](https://github.com/perushevandkhmelev-agency/react-native-track-player/tree/edge-2)

This 3rd party package is working entirely fine except app launch issue.
First time the app is launch and can do other stuff and play audio. Then we kill the app and again try to launch the app but it fails. Then we have to kill the app and again try to launch the app so it launches successfully. After playing audio there is this app launch issue. Please let me know if anyone has a fix for it.

Comment: This question would be more complete if it included details of the app launch issue - any error messages, statuses, logs... etc.

Comment: I would love to add that but there is none. No errors no warnings. Just it get stucked if i kill app when an audio is in play mode then i open the app it stucks then i kill and again open then everything works as expected. only issue i am facing that when an audio is playing then i kill the app then there is app launch issue only once :(